# size of page in html and css

Tags: html, css

I design something using HTML and CSS and see its output in my web browser. When I resize the web browser my design changes according to the size of the web browser. How can I fix the size of my web page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<title>
  my first page
</title>
<body>
 <h1 style="font-type:italic;color:blue;text-align:center">
   if music be the food of love, play on.</h1>
 <h1>
   If music be the food of love, play on.
 </h1>
 <h1>
  If music be the food of love, play on. </h1>
 <h1> If music be the food of love,
  play on.
 </h1 >
</body>
</head>
```

Comment: ...what? This question needs pictures, and a bit more advanced code than a simple flow-layout block (with too many `h1` elements, only 1 allowed per page).

Comment: assign min-width for your body or main wrapper.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes That's not necessarily true with an HTML5 doctype - at least from a technical standpoint. SEO-wise, maybe a different story.

Comment: Yeah well I know it's not defined by the standards, and that with sectioning content it's even recommended to have multiple `h1`s for the different levels - point was mainly that an HTML page shouldn't consist of *only* 3 `h1` tags  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is not contained in any parent container. (Except the default `<body>` tag)

You have to use a container and specify a "size" of said container.

- Specify a size for the body tag, using css.
  or
- Put your markup in a containing DIV, and apply css on the DIV to give it a specific width value

Answer (score 1):

You need to to fix the size of your body element, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24995652/3743987).
However, you should consider to use **`media query`** to set a different (the optimal) size for each devices.
[Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) you can find a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
      min-width: 500px;
}
```